# How to run a function inside AJAX success with process data and content type set to false?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with php, boostrap, ajax and jquery. On form submit, I use ajax to upload an image and store the data in the database. The data consists of firstname, middlename, lastname and the image.

It works fine and everything is stored in the database and the image was also uploaded with no error or warnings, but the modal function inside `success` isn't called. Is this due to the `processData` and `contentType` being set to false? How can I make it work?

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" name="fname" id="fname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middlename" name="mname" id="mname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" name="lname" id="lname">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Biography" name="biog" id="biog">
    <input type="file" name="profpic" id="profpic" class="none">
    <input type="file" name="coverphoto" id="coverphoto" class="none">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit" id="submitprofile">
    <button id="cancelme" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// require connection
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/dbconnect.php');

// set selected database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"profilecreator");

// sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO profiles (firstname,middlename,lastname,biography,profpic,coverphoto) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// prepare and bind
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbcon,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ssssss',$firstname,$middlename,$lastname,$biography, $profpic, $coverphoto);

    // set upload directory
    $uploads_prof = 'uploads/prof/';
    $uploads_cover = 'uploads/cover/';

    // set the variable values from javascript or jquery ajax post data 
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $middlename = $_POST['mname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
    $biography = $_POST['biog'];

    $profpic_filename = $_FILES['profpic']['name']; // profile pic filename
    $profpic_tmp_name = $_FILES['profpic']['tmp_name']; // tempory filename
    $profpic_target_file = $uploads_prof.basename($_FILES['profpic']['name']); // target file of the profile pic


    $coverphoto_filename = $_FILES['coverphoto']['name']; // profile pic filename
    $coverphoto_tmp_name = $_FILES['coverphoto']['tmp_name']; // tempory filename
    $coverphoto_target_file = $uploads_cover.basename($_FILES["coverphoto"]["name"]); // target file of the coverphoto

    $profpic = $uploads_prof.$profpic_filename;
    $coverphoto = $uploads_cover.$coverphoto_filename;

    $uploadprof_flag = 1;
    $uploadcover_flag = 1;

    // create an associative array of the profile without values
    $json_profile = array(
        'firstname'=>'',
        'middlename'=>'',
        'lastname'=>'',
        'biography'=>'',
        'profpic'=>'',
        'coverphoto'=>''
        );

    // check if profile picture is a valid image
    if(isset($profpic_filename)){
        $check = getimagesize($profpic_tmp_name);
        if($check!==false){
            $uploadprof_flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            echo 'File is not an image';
            $uploadprof_flag = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        $profpic = null;
    }

    // check if coverphoto is a valid image
    if(isset($coverphoto_filename)){
        $check = getimagesize($coverphoto_tmp_name);
        if($check!==false){
            $uploadcover_flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            echo 'File is not an image';
            $uploadcover_flag = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        $coverphoto = null;
    }

    /*Check if profile pic exists*/
    if(file_exists($profpic_target_file)){
        echo 'Sorry, file already exists.';
        $uploadprof_flag = 0;
    }

    /*Check if coverphoto exists*/
    if(file_exists($profpic_target_file)){
        echo 'Sorry, file already exists.';
        $uploadprof_flag = 0;
    }

    // check if flag is 1 upload the file else do not upload
    if($uploadprof_flag === 1){
        move_uploaded_file($profpic_tmp_name, $profpic_target_file);
    }
    else{
        echo 'sorry your file was not uploaded';
    }

    if($uploadcover_flag === 1){
        move_uploaded_file($coverphoto_tmp_name, $coverphoto_target_file);
    }
    else{
        echo 'sorry your file was not uploaded';
    }

    // execute prepared statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // or $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";    

    // set values for the associative array and encode it to json format, then write it
    $json_profile['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $json_profile['middlename'] = $middlename;  
    $json_profile['lastname'] = $lastname;
    $json_profile['biography'] = $biography;
    $json_profile['profpic'] = $profpic;
    $json_profile['coverphoto'] = $coverphoto;
    file_put_contents('api/profile.json',json_encode($json_profile),FILE_APPEND);

// close connection
mysqli_close($dbcon); 
?>
```

**Here's my jquery code**

```
$("#form-info").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var mname = $("#mname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var biog = $("#biog").val();
    var profpic = $("#profpic")[0].files[0];
    var coverphoto = $("#coverphoto")[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('fname',fname);
    formData.append('mname',mname);
    formData.append('lname',lname);
    formData.append('biog',biog);
    formData.append('profpic',profpic);
    formData.append('coverphoto',coverphoto);

    if(fname!==''||mname!==''||lname!==''){
        $.ajax({
            url:'createprofile.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $("#myprofile").modal('show');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus+' '+errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }   
    else{
        alert("Fields must not be empty except for the upload files");
    }

});
```

**Here's the code for my modal**

```
$("#myprofile").modal('shown.bs.modal',function(){
    $.getJSON('api/profile.json',displayProfile,'json');
});

var displayProfile = function(data){

    // initialize values
    var firstname = data.firstname;
    var middlename = data.middlename;
    var lastname = data.lastname;
    var biography = data.biography;
    var prof_pic = data.profpic;
    var cover_photo = data.coverphoto;

    // set values
    $("#myfirstname").text(firstname);
    $("#mymiddlename").text(middlename.substr(0,1)+".");
    $("#mylastname").text(lastname);
    $("#mybiography").text(biography)
    $("#myprofpic").attr('src',prof_pic);
    $("#mycoverphoto").css("background-image",cover_photo);
};
```

The bootstrap modal isn't showing up.

Comment: there is no problem with this code.

Comment: So your issue is just regarding this: `$("#myprofile").modal('show');`??? The console.log output expected result in console? If so, you just didn't provided the relevant code regarding the modal part and this has nothing to do with the ajax request

Comment: Did you get the `console.log`?  If you ignore the ajax and enter `$("#myprofile").modal('show');` in the console, does it show?  Please read this [mcve] - specifically the minimal part - only include relevant code.  As it is, we don't know which part of the code you are having issues with.

Comment: processData affects what is send to the server, so the processing of the formData. If you see the data appearing in the database that should be alright. If your `success` function is not called the createprofile.php does not send status code 200. Check with developer tool the request status. If fine (e.g. 200), check console. You should see the response there.

Comment: Provide the code of your modal also.

Comment: i use the console.log so i can see the success message when i inspect element on firefox and i see it right away. i also check my localhost and the files are stored in the database, and the uploads folder contains the 2 images for the profile picture and cover photo..  the createprofile.php file also writes a json file upon submit,  

i'm trying to use the $("#myprofile").modal('show'); to show the result on my page, the modal use $.getJSON to get the data of the written json file upon submit.  

my main problem is the modal doesn't show up

Comment: @Aakash yes "200 POST createprofile.php"  appears

Guys i edited the question i provided the codes now. thanks